# Positioning text inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a popup with some information.
I like to have the word "Actief" at the top right corner of the popup (always).
But it doesn't work with margin or padding.
The Image is blocking the word.
This is what I tried.
    `<h6 style="color: Green;float: right;/* position: absolute; */z-index: 9999999999999999;margin-top: 0px;display: block;/* margin-bottom: 60px; */">Actief</h6>`

My complete file:
https://jsfiddle.net/oynrwo4c/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to position it absolutely by adding the following styles:

```
.popup_body {
  position:relative;
}
```

And then give the h6 `position:absolute;` `top: 0;` and `right:0;` This will ensure it is always in the top right corner.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/oynrwo4c/3/) is a link to the updated fiddle with my code suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `position: absolute` to the same element for it to position itself as per the viewport.

Provide the following css to the `Actief` element:

```
h6 {
  color: Green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999999999999;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oynrwo4c/5/

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to add the following CSS to your element:

```
h6 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle that shows how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/oynrwo4c/4/

Put simply, the CSS above tells browser to render element h6 absolutely positioned 20px from top and 20px from the right edge. Absolutely positioned elements "jump out of the flow", and don't stack with other elements, meaning you can place them anywhere you want.

Also, you should mark your element div#popup as relative:

```
#popup {
    position: relative;
}
```

This ensures that h6 will be placed absolutely, but relative to the parent, meaning you can now also move the parent popup anywhere you wish, retaining proper positioning of h6 (just imagine your popup has an ability to be draggable).

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oynrwo4c/7/

However, I advise to avoid using inline CSS whenever possible.

1. It's very unreadable
2. Many modern browsers will render your page significantly slower. Sometimes this difference will hardly be noticeable, but in cases of iterative rendering (rendering many elements in the loop, like lists), browser will have to calculate styles every time it renders an element.

Here's an example:

http://jsbench.github.io/#a9283bb254143ea63d7c

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

'Absolute' value of 'position' property lets us place the element by settings offsets of its closest positioned ancestor (by 'positioned' I mean the one with 'position' value other than 'static' (default)).

```
<h6 style="color: Green; position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; margin: 0;">Actief</h6>
```

As you see I set the position absolute to the element and 'top' and 'right' properties. You can alter their values to get the offsets you want.

JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/La5j71qs/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `position: fixed;` style for your html element first. and then you can use `top` / `left` with settings for pixels, percentage or viewport to set where you want it to be and what to depend on.

example: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oynrwo4c/6/)

```
<h6 style="color: Green; position: fixed; top: 20vh; left: 25vw; height: auto; margin: auto;">Actief</h6>
```

You can read more about this: [css position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute position. I don't know why you have commented your code.

```
 <h6 style="color: Green;float: right; position: absolute; z-index: 9999999999999999;margin-top: 0px;display: block; top: 20px; right: 30px;">Actief</h6>
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oynrwo4c/2/)

Answer (score 0):

change position html code Like

```
    <div id="popup" style="position: fixed; top: 15%; width: 70%; height: auto; margin: auto; z-index: 99999; left: 15%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 1px 6px 4px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; display: block;">
    <div class="popup_body" style=" height auto;">
        <img src="http://www.ozmo.nl/images/logo.svg" width="150" style="float: center;">
        <h6 style="color: Green;float: right;/* position: absolute; */z-index: 9999999999999999;margin-top: 0px;display: block;/* margin-bottom: 60px; */">Actief</h6>
        <h4></h4>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h4 style="margin-top: 10px;"><u>We hebben een storing, we doen er alles aan om het op te lossen!</u></h4>
                    </td>
                    <td style=" width 4%; vertical-align top;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>08:56<h6>  Momenteel kampen wij met een storing, we zoeken nog naar het probleempje</h6><br></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h4 style="margin-top: 10px;"><u>We have a storing, we do everything to fix it!</u></h4></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h6 style="margin-top: 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</h6></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button style="padding: 10px; float: right;" class="close_button" onclick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button>
    <button style="padding: 10px; float: right;" class="close_button" onclick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oynrwo4c/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="popup" style="position: fixed; top: 15%; width: 70%; height: auto; margin: auto; z-index: 99999; left: 15%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 1px 6px 4px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; display: block;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: auto;"><img src="http://www.ozmo.nl/images/logo.svg" width="150" style="float: center;"><h6 style="color: Green;float: right;z-index: 9999999999999999;margin-top: 0px; position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 10px">Actief</h6><table><tbody><tr><td><h4 style="margin-top: 10px;"><u>We hebben een storing, we doen er alles aan om het op te lossen!</u></h4></td><td style=" width: 4%; vertical-align: top;"></td></tr><tr><td>08:56<h6>  Momenteel kampen wij met een storing, we zoeken nog naar het probleempje</h6><br></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><h4 style="margin-top: 10px;"><u>We have a storing, we do everything to fix it!</u></h4></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><h6 style="margin-top: 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</h6></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div><button style="padding: 10px; float: right;" class="close_button" onclick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button style="padding: 10px; float: right;" class="close_button" onclick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `z-index` and `position: absolute;`

try this

```
<h6 style="color: Green;float: right;margin-top: 0px;display: block;margin-right: 25px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="popup" style="position: fixed; top: 15%; width: 70%; height: auto; margin: auto; z-index: 99999; left: 15%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 1px 6px 4px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; display: block;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: auto;"><img src="http://www.ozmo.nl/images/logo.svg" width="150" style="float: center;"><h6 style="color: Green;float: right;/* position: absolute; */z-index: 9999999999999999;margin-top: 0px;display: block;/* margin-bottom: 60px; */">Actief</h6><table><tbody><tr><td><h4 style="margin-top: 10px;"><u>We hebben een storing, we doen er alles aan om het op te lossen!</u></h4></td><td style=" width: 4%; vertical-align: top;"></td></tr><tr><td>08:56<h6>  Momenteel kampen wij met een storing, we zoeken nog naar het probleempje</h6><br></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><h4 style="margin-top: 10px;"><u>We have a storing, we do everything to fix it!</u></h4></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><h6 style="margin-top: 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</h6></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div><button style="padding: 10px; float: right;" class="close_button" onclick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button style="padding: 10px; float: right;" class="close_button" onclick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
h6 span{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" style="position: fixed; top: 15%; width: 70%; height: auto; margin: auto; z-index: 99999; left: 15%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 1px 6px 4px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; display: block;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: auto;"><img src="http://www.ozmo.nl/images/logo.svg" width="150" style="float: center;"><h4></h4><h6 style="color: Green;float: right;/* position: absolute; */z-index: 9999999999999999;margin-top: 0px;display: block;/* margin-bottom: 60px; */"><span>Actief</span></h6><table><tbody><tr><td><h4 style="margin-top: 10px;"><u>We hebben een storing, we doen er alles aan om het op te lossen!</u></h4></td><td style=" width: 4%; vertical-align: top;"></td></tr><tr><td>08:56<h6>  Momenteel kampen wij met een storing, we zoeken nog naar het probleempje</h6><br></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><h4 style="margin-top: 10px;"><u>We have a storing, we do everything to fix it!</u></h4></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><h6 style="margin-top: 10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</h6></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div><button style="padding: 10px; float: right;" class="close_button" onclick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button style="padding: 10px; float: right;" class="close_button" onclick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>
```

Hope this helps.